# Wiring Bootstrap-switch to knockout observable

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js

I am looking at this example http://jsfiddle.net/meno/MBLP9/ for wiring up the on change event of a bootstrap button.  I am having trouble following how to relate this to another knockout observable.

I have an observable

```
self.IsAggregate = ko.observable(modeldata.SelectedItem.Aggregate);
```

Which has a default value on load, I am trying to wire this into the switch.  I do not understand the syntax in the fiddle as well

How are they defining a `:` for the observables and not an `=`?  When I try this Javascript throws a syntax error.

Ultimately I am trying to replace `on` with `IsAggregate`

My viewmodel and binding

```
//Registering switches
$("[name='toggleCatalog']").bootstrapSwitch();
    $("[name='toggleAggregate']").bootstrapSwitch();
var ViewModel = function(modeldata) {
        var self = this;
        self.on = ko.observable(true),
        self.SelectedCatalog = ko.observable(modeldata.SelectedCatalog);
        self.IsAggregate = ko.observable(modeldata.SelectedItem.Aggregate);
        self.IsEnabled = ko.observable(modeldata.SelectedItem.Enabled);
        self.CatalogConfiguration = ko.observableArray([]);
        self.ColumnDropdown = ko.observableArray([]);
        };

$(document).ready(function () {
        var model = new ViewModel(modeldata);
};
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the fiddle code , he created a binding handler for the bootstrap switch which update the knockout when the switch is done:
in the init function

```
init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
        var $elem = $(element);
        $elem.bootstrapSwitch();
        $elem.bootstrapSwitch('setState', ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor())); // Set intial state
        $elem.on('switch-change', function (e, data) {
            valueAccessor()(data.value);
        }); // Update the model when changed.
    },
```

he gets the control that knockout property is binded to and uses jquery to to put handler to update knockout property when 'switch-change'

and if there is update and the new value is not the current value he updates the knockout

```
update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
    var vStatus = $(element).bootstrapSwitch('state');
    var vmStatus = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
    if (vStatus != vmStatus) {
        $(element).bootstrapSwitch('setState', vmStatus);
    }
}
```

for more reference about the custom binding please visit:
http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html

For ":" question , in your code you defined your model as a function so we use the symbol "=" to define its properties
while in the fiddle code , he use object so we use ":" to define its properties

Comment: I see, that makes more sense. So can the binding handler be wired to my observable and instantiated by `var model = new ViewModel(modeldata);`?

Comment: I think this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/MBLP9/29/ will be what I need, I was able to get the update to work with the function model.

Comment: Also it turns out the files from github/nuget are different than the files used in that fiddle.

Answer (score 9):

I don't know exactly since which version the above stopped working. I had to modify the accepted solution to get it working for me and wanted to share:

```
/**
 * Knockout binding handler for bootstrapSwitch indicating the status
 * of the switch (on/off): https://github.com/nostalgiaz/bootstrap-switch
 */
ko.bindingHandlers.bootstrapSwitchOn = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
        var $elem = $(element);
        $elem.bootstrapSwitch();
        $elem.bootstrapSwitch('state', ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor())); // Set intial state
        $elem.on('switchChange.bootstrapSwitch', function (event, state) {
            valueAccessor()(state);
        });
    },
    update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
        var vStatus = $(element).bootstrapSwitch('state');
        var vmStatus = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
        if (vStatus != vmStatus) {
            $(element).bootstrapSwitch('state', vmStatus);
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: I'm implementing this now, and appreciate your work @Peter! However, it appears there must be new changes to make to this yet again. I'm posting my latest version in a separate answer. .. but, couldn't have done it w/o you.

Answer (score 1):

Based on @Peter's answer, improved yet again...

```
/**
* Knockout binding handler for bootstrapSwitch indicating the status
* of the switch (on/off): https://github.com/nostalgiaz/bootstrap-switch
*/
ko.bindingHandlers.bootstrapSwitchOn = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
        $elem = $(element);
        $(element).bootstrapSwitch({
            onSwitchChange: function (event, state) {
                event.preventDefault();
                valueAccessor()(state);// Update the model when changed.
                return;
            }
        });
        $(element).bootstrapSwitch('state', ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor())); // Set intial state
    },
    update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
        var vStatus = $(element).bootstrapSwitch('state');
        var vmStatus = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
        if (vStatus != vmStatus) {
            $(element).bootstrapSwitch('state', vmStatus);
        }
    }
};
```

The first thing most noticeable, is I pass in an `onSwitchChange` function as part of an `options` object. But, theres other tiny edits beyond that...

Answer (score 0):

There is also a handler for knockout mentioned in the bootstrap-switch github page. 
Seems to handle bootstrap switch options and template bindings in cleaner way

```
ko.bindingHandlers.bootstrapSwitch = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
        //initialize bootstrapSwitch
        $(element).bootstrapSwitch();

        // setting initial value
        $(element).bootstrapSwitch('state', valueAccessor()());

        //handle the field changing
    $(element).on('switchChange.bootstrapSwitch', function (event, state) {
            var observable = valueAccessor();
            observable(state);            
        });

        // Adding component options
        var options = allBindingsAccessor().bootstrapSwitchOptions || {};
        for (var property in options) {
            $(element).bootstrapSwitch(property, ko.utils.unwrapObservable(options[property]));
        }

        //handle disposal (if KO removes by the template binding)
        ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(element, function () {
            $(element).bootstrapSwitch("destroy");
        });

    },
    //update the control when the view model changes
    update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
        var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());

        // Adding component options
        var options = allBindingsAccessor().bootstrapSwitchOptions || {};
        for (var property in options) {
            $(element).bootstrapSwitch(property, ko.utils.unwrapObservable(options[property]));
        }

        $(element).bootstrapSwitch("state", value);        
    }
};
```

Courtesy :
[knockout-bootstrap-switch](https://github.com/pauloortins/knockout-bootstrap-switch)